# Como dar manutenção em sistemas com gettext?

Tags: php, tradução

Desenvolvi um sistema utilizando a biblioteca `php-gettext` e seguindo esse [tutorial](http://www.devin.com.br/php-gettext/) .

Tudo funcionou normalmente e a troca de idiomas está ok, porém esse sistema vai sofrer mudanças com o tempo e novas strings surgirão bem como outras sairão do sistema.

Como faço para quando mudar o arquivo principal .pot, eu não perca as traduções já existentes nos arquivos .po?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu resolvi o problema gerando o arquivo `.pot` da mesma forma de quando o criei. Depois abri o arquivo "*.po*" (com as traduções) no `PoEdit` e utilizei o menu `Catálogo > "Atualizar do Arquivo POT`.

Esta função mantém os campos traduzidos.